# For exits loop before reaching range limit

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

First of all sorry for any common mistake. I'm not a native english speaker and I'm new to python.

As `lug_par` is a list with 4 items, the second `for` loop should do 4 iterations. In the third `for` loop the condition of the if is true so it should execute the break and get out of the loop. My problem is that it doesn't get into the third iteration, as if the `len(lug_par)` was 2 and not 4. It jumps straight into the `cont_y = cont_y + 1`

```
import re

string = "R(95DHS(60PST_35FDP_05MTR)_05A(95DHS"

lug_par = [s.start() for s in re.finditer('\(', string)]
lug_par_cierra = [s.start() for s in re.finditer('\)', string)]

cont_y = 0
for i in (0, len(lug_par_cierra)):
    cont_x = 0
    for j in (0, len(lug_par)):
        if(lug_par[cont_x] > lug_par_cierra[cont_y]):
            c = lug_par.index(cont_x)
            borra = lug_par_cierra.index(c)
            break
        else:
            print lug_par[cont_x]
            cont_x = cont_x + 1
    cont_y = cont_y + 1
```

Comment: I get "IndexError: list index out of range" on the third iteration when I try to run this

Comment: Because you are iterating on a tuple instead of a range probably?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: You need `range` if you don't mean to iterate two times on each loop.

Comment: Also you are not using `i` or `j` anyway(at least not in this code). Why don't you directly iterate over `lug_par_cierra` and `lug_par`? Maybe smth like, `for _ in lug_par_cierra:`

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot the calls to `range()` in the `for-loops`. It should work as you expect once they are corrected.

Here is the corrected `code`:

```
import re

string = "R(95DHS(60PST_35FDP_05MTR)_05A(95DHS"
lug_par = [s.start() for s in re.finditer('\(', string)]
lug_par_cierra = [s.start() for s in re.finditer('\)', string)]
cont_y = 0

for i in range(0, len(lug_par_cierra)): #range() added
    cont_x = 0
    for j in range(0, len(lug_par)):    #range() added
        if(lug_par[cont_x] > lug_par_cierra[cont_y]):
            c = lug_par.index(cont_x)
            borra = lug_par_cierra.index(c)
            break
        else:
            print lug_par[cont_x]
            cont_x = cont_x + 1
    cont_y = cont_y + 1
```

Comment: @Lafexlos Ah yes, I missed that one as well!